# Is there a setting for "Extensions to Delete on Clean" in Visual Studio 2012 for a C# project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I just can't find this setting in VS 2012, but it is described in the [Visual Studio documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8x480de8.aspx). Is it not available for C# projects? Or where can I find it?

> **Extensions to Delete on Clean**
>
> The Clean option (Build menu) deletes files from the intermediate
>   directory where a project's configuration is built. Files with
>   extensions specified with this property will be deleted when Clean is
>   run or when you perform a rebuild. In addition to files of these
>   extensions in the intermediate directory, the build system will also
>   delete any known output of the build regardless of where it is located
>   (including intermediate outputs such as .obj files). Note that you can
>   specify wildcard characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specifically for C++ projects. The topic you linked to is located in the parent topic "Property Pages (C++)" which itself is part of "Visual C++ -> Creating and Managing Visual C++ Projects".

Comment: So this simply doesn't apply for C# projects? I still think it would be usefull.

Comment: @Staeff: As I said, it applies only to C++ projects. The context of the help page is relevant here. As far as I know, there is no equivalent setting for C# projects. The project properties differ greatly from language to language.